# Can INA219 be used to power AND report to an arduino or raspberry pi board?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, i2c

I've been trying to use the [ina219](https://www.adafruit.com/product/904) current sensor to measure the current drawn by a raspberry pi. But all tutorials I find on the web only measure the current of another circuit (like an LED that is powered by a battery: [this is the most referred I've seen around](https://www.rototron.info/raspberry-pi-ina219-tutorial/)).

I tried powering the Pi through the ina219, but it does not turn on. If I connect it in parallel (the battery goes through the sensor, to the Pi, AND directly to the Pi), it turns on, but I don't know if it is a good practice.

What I need is the Raspberry Pi to measure the current drawn by the Pi itself from a battery. If INA219 is not suitable, are there other options?

Comment: Can you post your circuit?

Comment: I figured out my ina219 was not working properly. Got a new one, now it works! Basically from the tutorial link I posted, you can plug an USB cable to the ina, and feed it into the pi and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured my INA was not working properly. Got a new one.

Then, if I connect both the I2C AND the supply through the ina, to the RPi, I get readings from it. No need to connect in parallel as I described.